# What is the font used in Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

What is the font family and the sizes used in MATH.SE content and headings?

Note that I'm not sure if it is the right place to ask this question. If not, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the CSS it appears to be Georgia.