# How to search on this site?

Tags: support, faq, search

When using this site, it is quite important to be able to find posts on this site which might be related to the question I am interested it - both to avoid duplication (i.e., not asking again questions that have been answered before) and to be able to access useful information already present on the site. However, this task is often quite difficult.

What are good ways to search on this site? Are there some tips and tricks and useful tools which should I know to search efficiently?

<sup>This post is made with the intention to create a community-maintained FAQ about search. (In particular, a post on meta is easier to edit and update than something in the help center.)</sup>

Comment: This is based on my previous suggestion here on meta: [Should we add external searches in some help pages about search?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27421) It was suggested by [quid](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46395591#46395591) and [Aloizio Macedo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352?m=46405070#46405070) that having a post on meta is better option than editing the help center. (Mainly because in this way the information can be improved and updated by regular users whenever needed.)

Comment: I will mention that the chatroom called "[In the search of a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26818#26818)" is also a suitable place where you can ask questions related to searching. (Or even if you are trying to search for a specific post.)

Comment: Thanks for starting this!

Comment: A great start, Martin $\huge{+1}$.

Comment: I also remember my question about [access to question posts from previous years](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/access-to-question-posts-from-previous-years), which was very helpful to me, as were the links to [Searching for questions asked between two dates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19463) and [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386).  I imagine the same can be done for searching for answers with similar criteria.  (Just linking all that here for quicker access).

Answer (score 32):

**Approach0**

Searching for a specific formula is often rather difficult. A tool which is very suitable for this is the [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/) search engine.

Some basic information can be found in [Guide for New Users](https://approach0.xyz/guide/) (which contains also animations of some examples). If you want to know more about the project, you can look at [the documentation](https://approach0.xyz/docs/).

Approach0 uses mathquill editor and also offers a handy-pad for entering mathematical expressions. But for people familiar with $\rm\LaTeX$/MathJax it might be much easier to enter the expression directly in this form using *raw query*. (And you can also copy-paste a formula into this field from the source of some post on the site.)

The search results are presented with their title, a short preview of the contents, and (for search results from Mathematics SE) their tags. One can click on the title to open a posting in a separate tab. One can also click on a tag below a search result, that will restrict the result list to postings with that tag.

You can find some useful information also in the post by the creator of this program: [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978)

For example, this is what you get if you [search for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k(k+1)}$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac1%7Bk(k%2B1)%7D%24&p=1). You can find many other examples of usage of this search engine if you look at [comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=approach0) and [chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=approach0) mentioning Approach0.

Although the ["searching" chatroom](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26818#26818) has a more general purpose, quite a lot of the conversation in that room was devoted to Approach0.

---

Some stuff which is useful to keep in mind when using this search engine:

- Recent posts can be missing among the search results - depending on when the index was last updated.
- Approach0 is able - at least to some extent - to find posts where the same expression is written differently. (For example, names of a variables are changed, the sides of an equation are exchanged, etc.) But since this have some limits, you should try to think about various ways of writing the same expression. For example, when looking for posts about limit of Cesàro mean, you could try to [search for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}n$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20a_k%7Dn%24&p=1),
  or [for $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20n%5E%7B-1%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20a_k%24&p=1),
  or [for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac1n%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20a_k%24&p=1),
  or [for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Ba_1%2B%5Cdots%2Ba_n%7Dn%24&p=1)
  Another example: You get different results if you [search for $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(x)%7Dx%24&p=1) and if you [search for $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20x%7Dx%24&p=1).
- There is a distinction between `\infty` and `+\infty`. For example, you get different results [for $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac1n)^n$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20(1%2B%5Cfrac1n)%5En%24&p=1) and [for $\lim_{x\to+\infty} (1+\frac1n)^n$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%2B%5Cinfty%7D%20(1%2B%5Cfrac1n)%5En%24&p=1) then the results are completely different.
- There is also a distinction between `|x|` and `\left|x\right|`, Approach0 treats these two differently as a result of [some technical considerations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2019/12/5). For example, compare the search for $\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\le\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$ [with](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%7Cx%2By%5Cright%7C%7D%7B1%2B%5Cleft%7Cx%2By%5Cright%7C%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%7Cx%5Cright%7C%7D%7B1%2B%5Cleft%7Cx%5Cright%7C%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%7Cy%5Cright%7C%7D%7B1%2B%5Cleft%7Cy%5Cright%7C%7D%24&p=1) and [without](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%2By%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx%2By%7C%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx%7C%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%7Cy%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cy%7C%7D%24&p=1) including `\left` and `\right`.
- Check the parentheses! An extra or missing parenthesis might go unnoticed in a displayed formula, but makes a difference on Approach0: [search for $\cos(x+y))$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos(x%2By%29)%24) vs [search for $\cos(x+y)$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos(x%2By)%24).

---

*Update:* As of June 2021, Approach0 supports an **extended query syntax.** It allows to combine queries with logical operators, limit the results to certain sites (e.g. MSE), search in titles, tags, and so on.

Some examples (taken from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58430215#58430215) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59034394#59034394) in the [In the search of a question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question) chat room):

1. Search for two formulas at the same time: [`OR content:$\cos x+\cos y+\cos z=1 $, AND content:$ \sin x+\sin y+\sin z=1$`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccos%20x%2B%5Ccos%20y%2B%5Ccos%20z%3D1%20%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24%20%5Csin%20x%2B%5Csin%20y%2B%5Csin%20z%3D1%24)
2. Limit data source to MSE: [`OR content:$\sin\left(\omega t \right)$, AND site:math.stackexchange.com`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Comega%20t%20%5Cright)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)
3. `\exact` specifier for symbols: [`OR content:$\sin\left(\omega \exact t \right)$`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Comega%20%5Cexact%20t%20%5Cright)%24)
4. Search for posts of some tags: [`OR content:$\sin\left(\omega t \right)$, AND tags:ordinary-differential-equations`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Comega%20t%20%5Cright)%24%2C%20AND%20tags%3Aordinary-differential-equations)
5. Search keywords in only title field: [`OR content:$\sin\left(\omega t \right)$, AND title:solving`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Comega%20t%20%5Cright)%24%2C%20AND%20title%3Asolving)
6. Use NOT clause to filter things: [`AND title:eigen, NOT title:vectors`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20title%3Aeigen%2C%20NOT%20title%3Avectors)

Comment: I was trying to edit, but it is very strange that the number $0$ appears as the letter $o$ in the post.

Comment: I'll mention that to make searching faster, sometimes I [use a bookmarklet](http://msleziak.com/various/bookmarklets.html) which opens a window with Approach0 search for the currently selected string.

Comment: @user9464 this seems to be a quirk of the specific font used for this site ([Georgia, I believe](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6657)): `$0$ 0 o O` renders as “$0$ 0 o O”.

Comment: Just wanted to find any q&A containing the numerical constant $0.091767$. ('ve used this constant (with some more digits) in an answer of mine. Pure text-search does not find matches, so maybe one must search for this numbers as a math expression. Now approach0 finds many mathces, but no relation to the digits of my number... now no more option?

Comment: Is this the post you are looking for—? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4538371 (I searched for `0.091767* user:1714`. The star operator is a wildcard, and the user operator searches within your posts.) Oh wait, is it that you wanted other posts containing this number? Then the search `0.091767*` might help. (But this latter search only brings up your post. Searching for `0.0917*` brings up two more, not sure how related.)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms for exact number search, the current approach0 is not suitable for this purpose. Use Google with keywords "0.091767" and site:math.stackexchange.com instead, although I do not find anything relevant also.

Comment: @WeiZhong - many thanks for the advice! I just didn't remember to parametrize google with "site:..." and expected that google does not evaluate the mathjax-formulae (because of not finding my number using standard method)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist -ahh,urrrks... could I only have had the idea with the star! Yes, that was my ansqwer and I wanted to know whether this number is known in other contexts... Thank you very much, I'm going to improve now my searches...

Answer (score 12):

**Lists of questions**

There are also various lists of questions which might help when searching for some topic (some of them generated by the Stack Exchange software, some of them created manually).

- If you click on [ask question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and fill at least the title (perhaps also tags) the software generates a list of questions that are similar. As pointed out by some users, this can be used basically as a search engine. See also: [Trying to ask a question provides better results than normal search.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26415)
- If you have already found a question which is close to what you are looking for (although perhaps not the exact fit), it might be useful to check also the [linked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/linked-questions/info) and [related](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/related-questions/info) questions which are shown in the sidebar on the right. Typically, they tend to be rather similar to the question you are currently viewing.

The following is useful mainly if you are looking for a problem which is rather common and you suspect that it has very likely been asked before.

- There are some lists of frequently asked questions which were collected by users of this site. Mainly [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868) and [Catalog of standard exercises](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16708). Some of posts from specific areas can be found here: [Would “organizer posts” be useful/welcome here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3967#4071)

Answer (score 11):

**Google**

You can simply use Google with the restriction to this domain, using (in addition to the search query) [site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com). (Of course, you can also use any other search engine where this restriction is possible.) For example, you can use the search: [triangular numbers site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=triangular+numbers+site:math.stackexchange.com) to get to relevant posts about triangular numbers.

Google indexes the whole page, which means that it searches for the keywords both in posts and in comments. Another possible advantage is that the ranking of results is provided by Google. (You might find the ordering chosen by Google better than the one obtained from built-in-search. It takes into account different things - depending on your preferences you might be more satisfied with this one.)

Sometimes also using Google Images might be useful. (For example, if you have seen the problem on the site before and remember that the question on the answer had picture. Or if you simply know that the solution can be illustrated by a nice picture.) Some examples: [harmonic series site:math.stackexchange.com](http://images.google.com/images?q=harmonic+series+site:math.stackexchange.com) or  [cobweb plot site:math.stackexchange.com](http://images.google.com/images?q=cobweb+plot+site:math.stackexchange.com).

A few other examples showing Google being used when searching for a specific problem can be found here: [How to search math terms/notations accurately and efficiently? Could some experienced users summarize some tips here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21900#21917) and [How to google search mathematical notions and expressions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055538#1099842)

Comment: Google *won't* work for [countries where Google is banned](https://www.quora.com/Is-Google-banned-in-any-country).  See [here](https://degooglisons-internet.org/en/) for reasons to avoid Google.

Answer (score 10):

**Built-in-search**

The site has built-in search engine - the search bar is near the top of the site. Notice that after [you get to search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=) a link with "Advanced Search Tips" become available - it contains various search modifiers. (Advanced search options can also be found [in the help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching).)

Some useful advice:

- Notice that search results can be sorted in various ways (relevance, date of posting, score of the post, date of the most recent activity).
- In this way you search *only in posts* - not in comments. (If you need to search in comments, you can find some advice in: [Searching comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3097) and [How to browse or search comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12142))
- Tags can be used to restrict your search. For example, instead of searching for all posts containing the name [Pascal](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pascal) you can restrict the search to [the posts tagged (binomial-coefficients)](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pascal+%5Bbinomial-coefficients%5D), if this is what you are interested in. You can use `-[tagname]` to get the post which do *not* have some specific tag - for example, the post with [Pascal tagged (binomial-coefficients) but not (probability)](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pascal+%5Bbinomial-coefficients%5D+-%5Bprobability%5D).
- Notice that if you search *only* using tags, then also the frequent tab becomes available. It lists the questions that have most links from/to other posts. For example, if you are looking for a question which is about some sum with binomial coefficients, then it is quite likely that it might be [tagged both (binomial-coefficients) and (summation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients+summation). If you suspect that it is a basic question which might have been asked several times in the past, you could try to go to questions having these two tags and then choose [the frequent tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients+summation?sort=frequent).
- Similarly, frequently asked questions tend to have many views, so if you are looking for such questions you can restrict the search to posts with large number of views, for example: [Pascal views:1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pascal+views%3A1000).

See also:

- If you browse through the posts tagged [search](/questions/tagged/search) here on meta, you can find plenty of useful information about searching. (In particular, some tips and tricks which might by useful in some situations.)

Comment: On the page displaying search result, I see four sorting options : Relevance, Newest, Votes, Active. In your first bullet point, you mention that one can sort by number of view but not by number of votes. Is this a mistake? If not, how do you sort results by number of views?

Comment: @ArnaudD. That was a mistake, I probably just remembered it wrong. I have added a separate bullet point mentioning that the search can be restricted using `views:` modifier - if this is too specific to be useful to new users, we can omit the part about the number of views.

Answer (score 3):

**Math search engines**

There are various tools online specifically for searching for mathematical content. [Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site/29267#29267) is already mentioned in a separate answer. Some other search engines include:

- [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/) which includes searching on several sites, including Mathematics Stack Exchange, MathOverflow and others. For example, here is [search for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k(k+1)}$](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En+%5Cfrac1%7Bk%28k%2B1%29%7D%7D%24). It was mentioned [also on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10169/how-to-search-for-a-formula-expression/20619#20619) and [on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/how-to-search-the-internet-for-strings-that-consist-mostly-of-math-notation/3095415#3095415).

Comment: There used to be [uniquation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniquation&room=46148), but that website seems to be no longer working.