# Can we have a feed of watched tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching

On the questions tab can we have a filter feature (I mean like frequented votes etc) of watched tags. I am aware that the tags that I have watched are demarked in a different colour. But I would like to discuss the pros and cons of getting a dedicated watched tags filter because I feel most people are well versed in certain specific areas of mathematics and would like to answer questions on that domain. This may not be so useful for asking questions as exploring newer areas of mathematics is generally encouraged upon. On the other hand its good for everybody that they answer questions on domains that they have command over. Any suggestions in this regard are welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The search query [intags:mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags:mine) returns only posts in your favorite tags. If you [sort by activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intags:mine) and perhaps add [is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=intags:mine+is:q) it should look similar to the list of questions in various tabs on the main site.

You can also use [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/357965/bounty), IIRC a filter with your favorite tags is created automatically. From here, you can also get an RSS feed with questions in those tags, see also: [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3403). (But it seems that you did not mean the word *feed* in the question in this sense.)

EDIT: Now the [custom filters feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-filters/info) - described in [Andrew T.'s answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29530/can-we-have-a-feed-of-watched-tags/29531#29531) - is available also on this site. (See also: [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326).) So you have another alternative at your disposal - creating a custom filter for your watched tags. (This is probably the simplest one.)

Comment: Is there a list of such search queries some where? These seem pretty powerful. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @mm-crj: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching (Also "Advanced search tips" on the search page).

Comment: @mm-crj Also the FAQ on the local meta might be useful - at least to give you further pointers: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Thank you both @Asaf Karagila and Martin Sleiziak .. that helped a lot ..

Answer (score 18):

[Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement) is now available on all SE sites.

One of the features is a filter to list only watched tags:

> [image: Custom Question Lists' filter]

Comment: I can't wait for it

Comment: Good. I always thought it was extremely dumb that if you try to look for unanswered questions with specific tags they're always sorted by votes, so you get the ancient questions with hundreds of votes and the unanswered questions that you actually want to see are dozens of pages back.