# Is it OK to ask approximately one question a day from old application exams?

Tags: support, asking-questions, etiquette

If I ask approximately one question a day (from old application exams) will it be considered flooding/spamming or is this perfectly legal?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the precise context, but generally I would say it is alright if and only if:

- You make a reasonable effort to present your questions according to our guidelines. See [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) In particular, explain the context of the question and possibly your own thoughts about it. Do not simply repost the question "as is"; this would be not well received independent of the volume.
- You follow up on your posts and do not just ask  it and then seem to forget about it.

In particular, combining both, take feedback you get on board. If you receive some type of complaint about one question, do try to avoid it for the next one.

It is also less of a concern  when it happens  over a reasonably varied selection of topics or at least in a common topic (which is likely given how you describe it).

Asking many very similar questions could raise a red flag.

Comment: regarding the tip to follow up on my posts...I think I read somewhere that you should not post comments like "thanks" or "oh that helped alot"...if the question is answered fully, is there really a reason to follow up?

Comment: *If* your post is clear enough that there are no requests for clarification and you get a complete answer, there is indeed not much need for any further action. You should accept an answer at some point; no need to rush it but it makes sense to do it in a timely manner (say a few days). However, it might happen that other users ask you questions to clarify etc. I meant that you should be responsive to such requests.

Comment: @splokk23 I will just add that it is also useful to search before posting whether the same problem hasn't already been solved on the site. (Maybe you'll find that many questions you're interested in have already been asked and answered.) Some tips here could help you with searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)