# Is there a page explaining how to use the search function?

Tags: support, search

I've been around here for a while, but I never really learned how to use the search function. I know there is a page introducing new users to LaTeX. Is there also a new page introducing users to the search function?

I know that if you click on the search bar, there is a small guide. But I am wondering if there is a page which explains things in more details.

Thanks!

Comment: Clicking on the search page pops-up a brief list of options, and at bottom right there is a link to "search help": [How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Some links are mentioned here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29266)

Comment: I closed as a duplicate. See in particular the answer about the built-in search. Please notify me if you think this is in fact not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you all for the info. This is indeed a duplicate but the other questions and the links provided here are very helpful.