# Should we be more harsh on questions with answers elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, allowed-questions, exact-duplicates

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373541/201-positive-integers-and-averages) and many others which I have seen, the question is an exact copy with little changes to itself on [quora](https://www.quora.com/201-positive-integers-are-written-The-first-and-the-last-one-are-equal-to-19999-The-rest-numbers-are-less-than-the-average-of-the-neighbouring-numbers-The-average-and-between-each-remaining-number-is-a-unique-number) or other sites. I left a comment on the post with reference to the quora post, however, IMHO, the OP could have done that themselves. Should we be more harsh on this? I am sure that many others have also faced this issue. After all , a simple search can provide an answer to a question. I believe that it is good if they(Referencing to everyone in general) try to find their question on the internet and if they do not understand the solution given, then ask it here with reference to the other website which they have seen that potential solution. If they do not do as such, I think that that is either down to laziness or negligence. Which is something that I am guilty of as well and must improve on.

I also think that if the community does emphasise this more, the chances of questions being answered in the comments will definitely decrease. Furthermore, I think that we should extend the duplicate functionality to websites like quora or AoPS . Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: One problem is, we want math.stackexchange to become the premier repository of mathematical knowledge on the internet. That would suggest that if there's an answer on quora or Wikipedia or AoPS then we should post a copy of it on our site.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of that. Albeit, it seems very time consuming copying over solutions from other webpages. Also, wouldn't that require some form of consent(permission), to reproduce material?

Comment: Well, it might be a tad unrealistic to hope to have all of math on our site. We may have to lower our expectations a little.

Comment: Posts that have been directly copy-pasted from elsewhere, especially when they give no context or further effort towards a solution, should be closed under existing policies. "I saw this problem and don't understand the answer" is a waste of time; "I saw this problem and follow the solution up to step 7, but I don't get how lemma A links to the equation B, is it something to do with C's theorem?" is at least workable.

Comment: How exactly would a duplicate closure direction to other websites work? "Answers" that just link to somewhere else without further explanation, and in particular those that become useless if the link goes bad, are already deleted network-wide. *Your answer is in another castle* would be an appropriate search in this regard.

Comment: I thought that maybe ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) could be a suitable tag here? I have also checked whether posting on SE and Quora has been discussed elsewhere. Among [the few results I found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcross-posting%5D+quora), this post on [meta.se] seems to be closest to this topic: [Am I allowed to indicate crosspost links in my questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293150)

Comment: One thing that can be done is to provide seach bar of approach zero, besides the ask question section.

Comment: Yeah that is useful. I only know that Approach zero can find posts on MSE and AoPS. @MartinSleziak is it possible to include quora and other math websites and forums in the search? Sorry if what i'm asking is stupid, i'm not very good with these tech things.

Comment: @Ajay Have you checked SearchOnMath - that's another search engine mentioned in the FAQ post: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) I am not the right person to ask about extending Approach0 - in any case, I would suggest to continue such discussion [in the chatroom dedicated to searching](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2022/2/5) - it seems a bit tangential here.

Comment: Stackexchange doesn't attempt to avoid duplicating knowledge that can be found elsewhere on the internet. "Your question can be answered by googling" isn't a reason to close a question, if the question is on topic and has not already been asked on math.stackexchange. People ask questions on this forum because they want answers from this community. For whatever reason, the *best* explanations often tend to appear on math.stackexchange. Even if an answer can be found elsewhere, a *more insightful* answer is likely to appear on math.stackexchange.

Comment: If a question is asked here with context, it's no more the question whose answer can be found by googling. Context isn't merely a honesty certificate, it's for answerers to make use of as they write their answer so they can tailor their efforts better to the poster. So googling could get you answers, but they mayn't be the answers you want. As for Quora, well, copy-pasting titles from Quora is going to get you in trouble here anyway (like in the linked question) and how reliable are answers on Quora, in any case? I can say with some confidence that the same question here gets better answers.

Comment: That doesn't mean that one shouldn't give credit, though. Answerers/Questions obtaining content from elsewhere should strive to give credit to that source, whether it be Quora, AoPS, a paper, or a book.

Comment: Nor, @Sarvesh does it mean users  are exempt from searching.  One of the downvote reasons on a question is "This question shows no research effort".

Comment: @amWhy Striving to give credit requires applying a non-zero amount of effort to search, so I have already made that point. Research effort is reflected in the context of the question so it doesn't consist of searching alone. As I mentioned earlier, if I see a question with context that may have been asked on another website e.g. on Quora, I would not close/downvote the question for a lack of research effort, but rather encourage answers that fit the OP's context and possibly improve on the answers in the other site. If it lacks context, it is poorly received in any case.

Comment: I am not speaking of giving credit to anyone on or off this site.  I agree with that.  I just don't want to see questions: "Problem statement. --------------------. Someone on quora said the answer was $\pi/2$. Can  someone give me all the steps?"

Comment: @amWhy Sure, such questions aren't going to be received well because it lacks context anyway. I believe such questions don't form the focal point of this discussion because we have a better reason to get rid of such questions than a lack of effort to search. What I consider to be debated here is questions which may be non-closable under a standard reason (alternate forms of context are present), but whose answer may be found by directed searching on , say Google or Quora. I'm saying such questions should remain open and be answered so as to reflect the provided context the best.

Comment: The reason I provide for this is that while Google, Quora, Reddit etc. may provide generic answers that do not deal with OP's situation with much specificity(or even correctness and readability, noting MathJax is available only here), I believe that we should give MSE the opportunity to exceed those sources in quality, particularly if the questions themselves are on-topic to start with. MSE's infrastructure and userbase already give it a good head start in the race for quality.

Comment: It’s an interesting question. One of the problems I have, and it may just be me, but the math.stackexchange search engine does not seem to be too smart. There are times when I know I have seen a question asked and answered, but no search I do  can find it. If that is indeed the case, then it is more understandable why duplicates arise.

Comment: This has scared me a little bit. Many times I have posted questions here the answers to which I had already found elsewhere. I have found that more often than not a helper here offers some new insights and, sometimes, completely new solutions.

Comment: @user1115542: I often struggle to find my own answers. One (not perfect) trick is to try and write a question; the automated search for duplicates/related when you are writing a question is much much better than the plain search.