# Is it a duplicate if the same question exists in another site?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, faq-proposed

I often see some questions which are the same or similar to other questions on another site (Like AOPS, Math Overflow, etc.)

Is it a duplicate if other questions in OTHER SITES can answer the question?

Comment: Some related posts here on meta: [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9210), [Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10072), [Exact duplicates of questions posted on MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11000) or [Should we be more harsh on questions with answers elsewhere?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34543) (Most likely you can find a few more related posts.)

Comment: Short answer: no, not a duplicate.  However if the same user is posting the same Question to other StackExchange site, this is called "cross-posting" and worth commenting upon if the same user has not already noted this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think an answer linking to and summarizing the "duplicate" would be appropriate in such cases. I have posted such answers a few times, usually marking them as community wiki.