# Add a list of FAQs

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates

I think that there should be a list of frequently asked math questions. Let a question be called a sub-duplicate of another question if it is that other question or it is closed as a duplicate of a sub-duplicate of that question (This definition is inductive.) We should have a list of questions together with their number of sub-duplicates with questions with high numbers of sub-duplicates at the top, so that new users know what questions are frequently asked. I think that this might reduce the number of duplicate questions on this site.

Comment: Relatively similar: [List of Generalisations of Common Questions](/q/1868) and [Coping with abstract duplicate questions.](/q/1756).

Comment: New users don't search, either the whole site, or lists of common questions. I've been here seven years, and i can barely search the site. If you want to spend some effort on reducing duplicate questions, I'd say the best thing you can do is get familiar with the resources @martinsleziak lists below, and start using them to close duplicate questions.

Comment: This is a feature request, whereas the proposed duplicate is a discussion.

Comment: mathlander  Your questions are natural for a user on this site who's been here six months, enough time to develop ideas to suggest for improvement.  I appreciate your instinct to want to improve this site.  But some of us have been on this ten, fifteen, even twenty times longer than you, and a lot of us have filled math meta with such suggestions.  I encourage you to search first, and if your question isn't answered, only then ask.

Comment: Using a different tag doesn't make it any less of a duplicate, wrt the question you asked, mathlander.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll at least mention what already is available if you look only at the direct duplicates (rather than recursive duplicates). And let me mention various other lists that exist.

- There already are some manually created lists of questions. Some of them which are available on the site are mentioned in the part about "[Lists of questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29269)" in the FAQ post: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) (And some of such lists have already been mentioned in the comments.)
- There exists a tag called [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on main. (And there is a tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on meta, too - but I suppose we're discussing mainly the main site.) And you can combine this tag [with another tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+binomial-coefficients) or with [any other search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+hockey+stick).
- On the main site you have [the frequent tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent) - which is based on the number of links. And you can look at the frequent tab [for any tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients?tab=Frequent) or [combinations of tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients+summation?tab=Frequent).
- You can create various queries in [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) - there is a table PostLinks where `LinkTypeId=3` means duplicate. (And `LinkTypeId=1` means a link.) See also: [Add a PostLinkTypes table to SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247194) and [Add a PostLinkTypes table to SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247194).

Here are some examples of such queries - they only count "direct" duplicates not "recursive duplicates". They are from this answer on Meta Stack Overflow: [Most frequent questions for a tag combination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420727#420732) - but the linked queries run on MSE rather than SO. You can use parameters of those queries to change whether you look at duplicates or links.

- [Most frequently linked questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1651719/most-frequently-linked-questions?linktypes=3)
- [Most frequently linked questions in the given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1651720/most-frequently-linked-questions-in-the-given-tag?linktypes=3&tagname=binomial-coefficients)
- [Most frequently linked questions with tag1 and tag2](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1651724/most-frequently-linked-questions-with-tag1-and-tag2?linktypes=3&tagname1=binomial-coefficients&tagname2=summation)

Creating a similar query with looking at all "recursive duplicates" in SEDE might be difficult. It goes beyond my knowledge of SQL. (Moreover, a query trying to do so for *all* posts at the same time would likely time out.)

Here you can find a query which looks at a single question and finds the linked posts: [Get all interlinked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307280#307303).
I have  modified the query to look [only at duplicates](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1681724/get-all-interlinked-questions-only-duplicate-links?PostId=1490794&Level=3&linktype=3) - and not all links. You can change the parameter Level to increase the depth of the search.